# How to run loop in between the values of list for e.g. List = [0, 417, 2050, 2221, 3039]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

> I want to run 1st loop from List[0] and List[1] and then 2nd Loop from List[1] and List[2] and so on

```
for i in range(0,len(List)):
   for z in range(data[i],data[i+1]):
        print("Hi")
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What is `data`? What is your output? What is the expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your code almost works, but is meaningless.
If you loop from index 0 to index 1, then from index 1 to index 2, it will be the same as if you loop from index 0 to index -1.

```
test_list = [0, 417, 2050, 2221, 3039]

test = []
test2 = []

for i in range(0, len(test_list)-1):
    for z in range(test_list[i], test_list[i+1]):
        test.append(z)
        print(f"Hi {z}")

# Will generate same result as
for i in range(test_list[0], test_list[-1]):
    test2.append(i)
    print(f"Hi {i}")

# Verify that
for z, i in zip(test, test2):
    assert z == i
```